# dynamically create property to class from a list of properties

Tags: python, class

I am trying to dynamically create some methods to a class but when I create an object of this class and access the properties, I always get the last value.

```
properties = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for p in properties:
    f = property(lambda self: p)
    print p # you see a, b, c
    print f # you can see it is 3 different objects
    setattr(MyClass, p, f)

obj = MyClass()
obj.a # returns c !!! why?
obj.b # returns c !!! why?
obj.c # returns c
```

### UPDATE

I was able to make it work using a function to create the method:

```
def create_function(p):    
    def f(self,):
        return p   
    return f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with using `property`. It's explained in the official FAQ as [Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result).

When you do this:

```
properties = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for p in properties:
    f = property(lambda self: p)
    print p # you see a, b, c
    print f # you can see it is 3 different objects
    setattr(MyClass, p, f)
```

… each `f` is a closure over the `p` variable.* This means that, when you call that `f`, it will return the current value of `p` within its defining scope, not the value of `p` at the time at which the closure was constructed. At the end of the loop, `p`'s value is `'c'`, so that's what all of your properties return.

You can get around this by (among other solutions**) using the "default value hack":

```
properties = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for p in properties:
    f = property(lambda self, p=p: p)
    print p # you see a, b, c
    print f # you can see it is 3 different objects
    setattr(MyClass, p, f)
```

Now, each property has a parameter named `p`, whose default value is the value of `p` at function definition time. When called (without supplying a `p` argument), the body ends up with a local variable `p` with that value, instead of a closure variable `p` referring to the non-local scope.

---

* Actually, it's not technically a closure, because the defining scope is global. But it acts the same as if it were done inside another scope.

** There's also the JavaScript idiom of creating a new scope to define the function within, `(lambda p: lambda self: p)(p)`, or `functools.partial`, or creating a callable object instead of a function, or… But, despite having the word "hack" in the name, the "default value hack" is a well-known Python idiom, enshrined in the docs and used within the stdlib, and it's usually the best answer, unless you have some *other* reason for another scope or a `partial` or a custom callable.

Comment: I see, thank you. I was also able to make it work using a function that will create my function. See the update on my post.

Comment: @YAmikep: As a side note, if you look at the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) docs for members of `function` and `code` objects, you can see how to test whether `p` is a local, closure, or global variable within the body. (You can also use `dis.dis` if you want to learn how to ready bytecode.) In more complex cases, it can be handy.